# ValueError: 'axis' entry is out of bounds // numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Here is my 2D numpy array:

```
returns = np.array([
 [ -4.78878057e-03   9.79090927e-03  -2.06883581e-03  -1.25786164e-02]
 [  5.79128440e-03  -2.85791008e-03   1.69555388e-03  -5.63798220e-02]
 [  5.73427375e-05   2.45043133e-02   8.55025651e-03  -4.53257790e-02]
 [  6.75441635e-03   8.70168484e-03   1.07547532e-02  -1.36919315e-01]
 [  6.68332655e-03   6.76498174e-03   3.08225775e-03   0.00000000e+00]])
```

And when I'm trying to calculate the STD for each column:

```
print np.std(returns, axis=1)
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
ValueError: 'axis' entry is out of bounds
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: I tried this on my machine with Python 2.7 and it works fine, but I did have to modify your declaration of `returns` to be syntactically correct by adding commas between each element in each array. Can you post the code for how you actually define `returns`?

Answer (score 5):

Check if your array is a 2-D array querying `a.ndim`. It may happen that you have a 1-D array of objects that, when printed, looks like a 2-D array. In this case you can convert it to a 2-D array doing:

```
a = np.array(list(a))
```

or

```
a = np.array(tuple(a))
```

Comment: Hi @Saullo, I tried to convert 1-D array, but it seems nothing happens

print('a = ', a.ndim) # a= 1

a = np.array(list(a))

print('a  after = ', a.ndim) #a after = 1

Do you have an idea what's happened?

Comment: @AzkarioRizky in your case could you please check what is the result of `type(a)`?

Answer (score 1):

Recently had this same problem:

```
np.sum(myndarray, axis=0)
```

was producing the "ValueError: 'axis' entry is out of bounds" error when executed inside a function called from a script. Strangely, when executing the line from the IPython shell it ran without a hitch (I checked that the myndarray variable was the same in both contexts).

I was working with Spyder, so perhaps it somehow got stuck in a weird state as a result of using the Python console + pdb, and/or IPython + ipdb, with the same set of variables. Restarting the IDE solved the issue, which also explains the others' inability to reproduce the bug.

Answer (score 0):

Michael,

I am not sure why you have the issue. It might be because of the way you are defining the 2D array (that's my only guess). I used the following code and it works properly:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([                                                                \
[ -4.78878057e-03,   9.79090927e-03,  -2.06883581e-03,  -1.25786164e-02],       \
[  5.79128440e-03,  -2.85791008e-03,   1.69555388e-03,  -5.63798220e-02],       \
[  5.73427375e-05,   2.45043133e-02,   8.55025651e-03,  -4.53257790e-02],       \
[  6.75441635e-03,   8.70168484e-03,   1.07547532e-02,  -1.36919315e-01],       \
[  6.68332655e-03,   6.76498174e-03,   3.08225775e-03,   0.00000000e+00]        \
])

std = np.std(arr,axis=1)
print std
```

and the answer will be:

```
[ 0.00803178  0.02526721  0.02593599  0.06308687  0.00281146]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is for someone who stumbles across this thread having the same error for a different reason.

I had the same error for any axis other than 0. I used `a.ndim` and saw there were 3 dimensions in the array. The fix was `array.reshape(x,y)` which made it 2d and then calling from the array worked.