# numpy sum gives error

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I wanted to used numpy.sum to find sum of multiplication of two arrays. I used the following code:

```
    p=10
    for i in range(0,p):
       popcost=numpy.zeros((1,p))
       cur=numpy.array(pop[i,:])
       popcost[0,i]=numpy.sum(numpy.dot(cur,fc),1)
```

pop is a (p*m) array itself and fc is a (1*m) array. I get the following error:

```
    'axis' entry is out of bounds
```

I can not figure out what is the problem. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Please post the entire error traceback.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ValueError: 'axis' entry is out of bounds // numpy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19572178/valueerror-axis-entry-is-out-of-bounds-numpy)

Comment: Take a look at the shape of `numpy.dot(cur, fc)`.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser i though if I have two 1D arrays, numpy.dot will give me an array with elements which are the result of elemntwise multiplication of the two 1D arrays. first I used numpy.multiply and I saw somewhere that numpy.dot works the same as numpy.multiply.

Comment: Can you update the question with a minimal complete example that we can copy and run? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you want to make the dot product of `pop` and `fc`. `numpy.dot` does it directly:

```
popcost = numpy.dot(fc, numpy.transpose(pop))
```

Edit : if you want the sum of the above:

```
popcost = numpy.sum(numpy.dot(fc, numpy.transpose(pop)))
```

Comment: No I wanted sum of the dot product of pop and fc. As I belive, the dot product should return a vector of the same size for pop or fc and then I wanted sum over all elements of this dot product vector.

Answer (score 0):

`numpy.dot` returns the dot-product of your two vectors (presumably what you wanted in the first place).

Being a single number, it doesn't have a `1.` dimension.

Aside from `sum` not doing anything for a single number: `numpy` counts things starting at `0`, not `1`.